# What would be a good Ubuntu/Alternative OS for my laptop?

Tags: 64-bit, system

I have an Asus R503U laptop with AMD C-60 1.0 GHz processor with 4 Gb of RAM. It is a 64-bit system. I also have a lower end Radeon Graphics card. Currently I am running Windows 10. I'm looking for something that would be easier on the processor and light on the ram to be able to play games and videos a little better.

Comment: It was a computer given to me so, getting a new one isn't much of an option for me when I dont have a job or any income.

Answer (score 0):

I find Lubuntu works well with less overhead dedicated to eye-candy. Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

You said it yourself: you've lower end graphics, but you want to play games, especially online ones. Lubuntu and Xubuntu can work for you, I'd even say Ubuntu with minimalistic desktop like blackbox or openbox will do (if you're willing to learn how to get them and use them). But no matter how minimalistic you go with your graphics, [your GPU will be a bottleneck](http://www.videocardbenchmark.net/gpu.php?gpu=Radeon+HD+7340&id=).

So here are your options:

- *All right:* install Lubuntu or Xubuntu 64 bit
- *Good:* install any version of Ubuntu, install a minimalistic desktop, like blackbox or openbox.
- *Best:* Give up on games <sub>(or get a newer computer)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Check it first with an i386 image of 14.04 LTS3 - If this does not run then take an i386 image of xubuntu - If not too, then test it with amd64 image of xubuntu - but then in the end this should run. As windowmanager only take xfce4 or only unity - in the beginning this is sufficient. and have fun !